# Unable to start titan with cassandra - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, graph-databases, titan, illegalargumentexception

Tried to start titan with the following code:

```
 TitanFactory.Builder config = TitanFactory.build();
    config.set("storage.backend", "embeddedcassandra");
    config.set("storage.directory", DIRECTORY);
    graph = config.open();
```

But, got the following exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation:
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.embedded.CassandraEmbeddedStoreManager
>         at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
>         at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
>         at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:407)
>         at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1320)
>         at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
>         at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:84)
>         at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:139)
>         at main.java.com.bag.server.database.TitanDatabaseAccess.start(TitanDatabaseAccess.java:55)
>         at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.(TestServer.java:105)
>         at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.main(TestServer.java:429)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>         at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
>         ... 14 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
>         at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.info(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:303)
>         at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.utils.CassandraDaemonWrapper.start(CassandraDaemonWrapper.java:69)
>         at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.embedded.CassandraEmbeddedStoreManager.(CassandraEmbeddedStoreManager.java:81)
>         ... 19 more

Trying to run it on Linux in Intellij - java.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you have not started Embedded Cassandra. Titan does not do that automatically for you I think. You can start embedded Cassandra with:

```
EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra();
```

for example. Or with

```
EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra("cassandra.yaml");
```

If you have a custom config to pass through.

**Edit:**

The above helper class is available by adding the following dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How do I get the EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper?

Comment: @user2524707 see my edit above. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: That seemed to have triggered new errors now:
http://pastebin.com/7G0UzxRr

Comment: So now it looks like it is trying to connect to the embedded cassandra but it has some pre-existing data saved. You might need to clear out the directory and check where the existing keyspace is coming from.

Comment: Okay, it seems that titan actually tries to start cassandra itself which causes this problems. I removed a log4j duplicate and I got a bit farther now.
Just this happens:
http://pastebin.com/2LGrw7Nw